# How to write data in a node.js stream without duplicates?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, web-crawler

This question is about a URL-crawler in node.js.
On the `start_url` URL he looks for links and "pushes" them to a .json-file (output.json).

How can I make sure that he does not "push" or "write" domains twice to output.json (so that I do not get duplicates)? I've been using the hash function but this has caused problems.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var start_url = ["http://blog.codinghorror.com/"]
var wstream = fs.createWriteStream("output.json");

// Extract root domain name from string
function extractDomain(url) {
    var domain;
    if (url.indexOf("://") > -1) { //find & remove protocol (http(s), ftp, etc.) and get domain
        domain = url.split('/')[2];
    } else {
        domain = url.split('/')[0];
    }
    domain = domain.split(':')[0]; //find & remove port number
    return domain;
}

var req = function(url){
    request(url, function(error, response, html){
      if(!error){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

        $("a").each(function() {
            var link = $(this).attr("href");
            var makelinkplain = extractDomain(link);

            start_url.push("http://" + makelinkplain);
            wstream.write('"http://'+ makelinkplain + '",');
        });
      }

        start_url.shift();

        if(start_url.length > 0) {
          return req(start_url[0]);
        }

          wstream.end();
    });
}

req(start_url[0]);
```

Comment: You can just store each domain in `Set` object and then just check the `Set` to see if it has already been stored before you write a new one out.

Comment: Why don't you just clear duplicates from output.json at the end of your function?

Comment: @nicandris why store duplicates in the first place? That idea really isn't efficient

Comment: @charlietfl I don't see a problem of efficiency if there are just a few hundreds of links

Comment: @jfriend00: I have had the same idea. Could you please give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just keep track of the previously seen domains in a `Set` object like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var domainList = new Set();
var start_url = ["http://blog.codinghorror.com/"]
var wstream = fs.createWriteStream("output.json");

// Extract root domain name from string
function extractDomain(url) {
    var domain;
    if (url.indexOf("://") > -1) { //find & remove protocol (http(s), ftp, etc.) and get domain
        domain = url.split('/')[2];
    } else {
        domain = url.split('/')[0];
    }
    domain = domain.split(':')[0]; //find & remove port number
    // since domains are not case sensitive, canonicalize it by going to lowercase
    return domain.toLowerCase();
}

var req = function(url){
    request(url, function(error, response, html){
      if(!error){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

        $("a").each(function() {
            var link = $(this).attr("href");
            if (link) {
                var makelinkplain = extractDomain(link);
                // see if we've already done this domain
                if (!domainList.has(makelinkplain)) {
                    domainList.add(makelinkplain);
                    start_url.push("http://" + makelinkplain);
                    wstream.write('"http://'+ makelinkplain + '",');
                }
            }
        });
      }

        start_url.shift();

        if(start_url.length > 0) {
          return req(start_url[0]);
        }

          wstream.end();
    });
}

req(start_url[0]);
```

Note: I also added a `.toLowerCase()` to the `extractDomain()` function since domains are not case sensitive, but a Set object is.  This will make sure that even domains that differ only in case are recognized as the same domain.

Comment: Thanks! After some time on certain websites I get this error in console: `if (url.indexOf("://") > -1) {` TypeError: Cannot read property `indexOf` of undefined. Isn't there another way to get the domain from the URL?

Comment: @MaximilianFuchs - Why not use the [node.js built-in url module](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parsing) for parsing the URL, but that specific error probably means you need some error checking on the `url` you pulled from the `<a>` tag as it may be non-existent.  You probably need an `if (link)` check before proceeding.  I've added that check to my answer.

Comment: I did my best but could you tell me why this does not work?: `url.parse(link).hostname;` after `$("a").each(function() {`

Comment: @MaximilianFuchs - "Does not work" is not a sufficient description of your problem to have any idea how to proceed.  What basic debugging did you do?  What exactly happened?  What errors did you see?  What did you output to the console?  We can help here only when you supply appropriate information and you should do your own basic debugging first and then, if you are still stuck, you should share everything you did and tried in your own debugging.

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not a function (> parse).
http://jsbin.com/dosemoforu/1/edit?js

Comment: @MaximilianFuchs - You have a conflict for the `url` variable name.  It is both the url module and a function argument name - you need to change the name of one of them.  If you need further help, I would suggest you post the actual code you're using in a new question since this question is already done.